# Create a global element in p5js

Tags: variables, global-variables, p5.js

Is there a way to make a graphics element global, in p5js? Right now I want to make the ellipse be global:

```
var bug = ellipse(0, random(height), 20, 20);

function setup() {
    createCanvas(500, 500);
    background(100);

 }

function draw() {

 }
```

I want to store the ellipse in a variable. But there's an error saying that "mySketch.js, line 1:Uncaught ReferenceError: ellipse is not defined". Can someone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ellipse()` function draws an ellipse, but it doesn't *return* anything, so you can't store the result of calling it in a variable.

I'm not totally sure what you're trying to do, but you have a couple options worth exploring:

1. You could store all of the values for your ellipse in variables like `ellipseX`, `ellipseY,` and `ellipseSize`.
2. You could create a class that stores the values you want. Shameless self-promotion: [here](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/p5js/creating-classes) is a tutorial on creating classes in p5.js.
3. You could draw the ellipse to a `p5.Graphics` and then store that `p5.Graphics` in a global variable. You can find more info about this in [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createGraphics).